# onBackPress() hides application after ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, actionview

I use two actions in some `activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone);
            startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
            Intent map = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + location);
            startActivity(map);
```

After calling one of this actions when I go back to my app and call `onBackPressed()`, it hides instead of going back to previous activity. Calling the app from the tray shows the same activity, but the problem still exists.

Comment: try do not use “geo:” use only location

Answer (score 0):

I have tested Intent.ACTION_DIAL, backButton works properly. Here is my scenario: 
Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Intent Dial
Backpressed() Dial screen -> Activity 2 Backpressed() -> Activity 1.

Comment: How can it help me?

Comment: I just want to notify you that onBackPress() doesn't hide application after intent dial or action_view. Make you didn't call finish() in your previous activities or set FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, everything should work fine.

Comment: Of course, it should not! But here what I have. I do not clear my activity stack or call `finishAffinity`. My logic is the same for both cases - using ACTION_VIEW and not - but works differently.